# Disable the firebug Break on unnecessary exceptions

Tags: firebug

I am using the firebug 1.9.2. It is having a feature break on error on console tab, whenever I run the application this feature breaks my application loading, which is sometimes more irritating, how to disable it??

Comment: Please, upgrade your Firebug (and your Firefox if necessary)! For your own information, the last version of Firebug is 1.11.2

Answer (score 3):

To the left of the Clear button there's an icon that toggles "Break on All Errors". Click on it.

Answer (score 0):

On Firefox Quantum (57.0), hit the stupid pause button in the Debugger... It toggles between 3 states... (Duh, obviously!)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Breaking_on_exceptions